# AWS serverless Nestjs app - Endpoints protected with Authorization header do not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

I deployed a Nest.js app using serverless.com

Here, is the lambda.ts file

```
import { configure as serverlessExpress } from "@vendia/serverless-express";
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import { ValidationPipe } from "@nestjs/common";

let cachedServer;

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    nestApp.enableCors();
    nestApp.useGlobalPipes(
      new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
        transform: true,
      })
    );
    await nestApp.init();
    cachedServer = serverlessExpress({
      app: nestApp.getHttpAdapter().getInstance(),
    });
  }

  return cachedServer(event, context);
};
```

and the serverless.yaml

```
service: invoice-management-api

frameworkVersion: "3"

plugins:
  - serverless-jetpack

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/**

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-west-1 # or whatever your region is

functions:
  api:
    handler: dist/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /{proxy+}
          cors:
            origin: "*" # <-- Specify allowed origin
            headers: # <-- Specify allowed headers
              - Content-Type
              - Authorization
            allowCredentials: true
```

The lambda deploys correctly and I am able to reach the **sign-in** which is unprotected (and that's fine) and I am able to retrieve the accessToken (JWT).
Once I try to touch another endpoint which is protected by an Authorization Bearer header, AWS responds with

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

It seems something goes wrong with the headers flowing through the Lambda to the Nest.js, or maybe a CORS problem. Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

grab the code that is works for me:

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import serverlessExpress from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { Callback, Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

let server: Handler;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  // here do what you need
  await app.init();

  const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  return serverlessExpress({ app: expressApp });
}

export const handler: Handler = async (
  event: any,
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback,
) => {
  server = server ?? (await bootstrap());

  try {
    const result = await server(event, context, callback);
    // Ensure the response from the server is in the proper format
    if (typeof result === 'object' && 'statusCode' in result) {
      // Set CORS headers
      result.headers = {
        ...result.headers,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Allow all origins
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type', // Allow specific headers
      };
    }

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during execution
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Allow all origins
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Internal Server Error',
      }),
    };
  }
};
```

and the config
service: NAME

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: REGION

functions:
  main:
    handler: dist/serverless.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /{proxy+}
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**